# Одинаковый url post_type WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте используется плагин **Custom Post Type UI**, который добавляет `post_type=types`. В итоге вывод материалов происходит по ссылке `site.ru/types/example`. Также есть вывод обычных записей `post_type=post`. Они выводятся по адресу `site.ru/catalog/tovar-title` Мне нужно, чтобы `site.ru/types/example` выглядел так `site.ru/catalog/example`, т.е. имел схожий адрес. Как это можно сделать?

Пробовал менять slug на catalog, чтобы совпадали url, однако ни один пост не отображался вообще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставьте в functions.php

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'types_remove_slug', 10, 3 );

function types_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $name ) {
 
    if ( 'types' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
      return $post_link;
    }
    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/catalog/', $post_link );
 
    return $post_link;
 
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'types_change_request', 10, 3 );
 
function types_change_request( $query ) {
 
     if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'types' ) );
     }
}
```

Comment: При клике на ссылку кидает правильно, однако 404. Если в ссылке поменять catalog->types, то вывод есть

Comment: @rutruyokko скорректировал второй хук в ответе. попробуйте новый код

Comment: божественно! благодарю :)